# Regular expression to extract SQL query

Tags: java, regex

Is there a regex which extracts SQL queries from a string? I'm ***NOT*** interested to validate any SQL syntax, rather, and only extracting a selection of SQL commands. This to parse a given SQL file/string in a flexible manner.

Given is the following SQL file/string example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    test_table
WHERE
    test_row = 'Testing ; semicolon';

SELECT * FROM another_test_table;

INSERT INTO 
    table_name 
VALUES 
    (value1,'value which contains semicolon ;;;;',value3,...);
```

Some pseudocode example would be: `^(UPDATE|SELECT|INSERT INTO)(.*)(;)$`. In the future I'm looking to extend this with all (possible) commands.

- Look for a starting match with either: (UPDATE|SELECT|INSERT|INTO)
- Zero or more `any character` (including whitespaces and newlines)
- Stop at `;`, which delimits the SQL query.

Whenever this would be possible via a regex the following Java code is able to extract all SQL commands:

```
final String regex = "LOOKING_FOR_THIS_ONE";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(content);

while (matcher.find()) {
  // matcher.group() now contains the full SQL command
}
```

Comment: Don't make your life difficult, put the queries in a properties file (with any key), load it, and iterate over the valueSet.

Comment: That ain't a possible solution, since I need to work with I get, I cannot demand a format as input. The input is a text file containing SQL commands, which I need to extract/parse.

Comment: Any chance for whoever created that string to include <query>...</query> ? Using plain text for structured information and forcing a developer to live with it seems a deliberate cruelty.

Comment: What is your pseudocode example matching? Looks almost exactly like one of the solutions, so what does not work?

Comment: Regexps are not a shortcut to parsing.  Learn to parse.

Answer (score 3):

I'll start off by saying that this is not a good way of doing it, and strongly urge you to find another method of doing it, preferrably tagging it properly where the statements are made, so you don't end up in this situation.

That being said, SQL requires it to start with one of the following; `DELETE`, `SELECT`, `WITH`, `UPDATE` or `INSERT INTO`. It also requires that the input ends with `;`.

We can use this to grab all sequences matching SQL with the following:

```
final String regex = "^(INSERT INTO|UPDATE|SELECT|WITH|DELETE)(?:[^;']|(?:'[^']+'))+;\\s*$";
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Group 1 now holds the operating word, in case you wish to filter valid SQL on `UPDATE` or `SELECT`.

See the regex in action, as well as a cave-at here:

https://regex101.com/r/dt9XTK/2

Answer (score 1):

You can match it "properly" as long as the semicolon is the last non-whitespace character on that line.

```
final String regex = ^(SELECT|UPDATE|INSERT)[\s\S]+?\;\s*?$

final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

`(?m)^(UPDATE|SELECT|INSERT INTO).*;$` should work.  This would extend the pattern to match over newlines.  It should be able to loop through and find all your SQL.

Looking at the example you provided it will match your commands until the `;`.  You can see the example used for testing [here](http://rubular.com/r/LTxNI9Seay).

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a language, create a lexer that tokenizes your string. Use [JFlex](http://jflex.de), which is a lexical analyzer generator. It generates a Java class that splits a string into tokens based on a grammar specified in a special file. Take the relevant grammar rules from [this file](http://yaxx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sql/scn2.l).

Parsing is a separate process than tokenization (or lexical analysis). You might want to use a parser generator, after lexical analysis, if lexical analysis is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

SQL is complicated enough that you will need context to find all statements, meaning that you can't do this with a regular expression.

For example:

```
SELECT Model FROM Product
WHERE ManufacturerID IN (SELECT ManufacturerID FROM Manufacturer 
WHERE Manufacturer = 'Dell')
```

(example comes from http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-nested-queries-sql-tutorial/). Nested queries can be nested multiple times, start with different values, etc. **If** you could write a regular expression for the subset you are interested in, it would be unreadable.

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr3.org/) has a [SQL 2003 grammar](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1302709126925/SQL2003_Grammar.zip) available (I haven't tried it).