# Regex for SQL insert query

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get the regex for SQL insert query. I need to extract the table name from the query. What should be the regex for this ? I am using Java

I looked at this link but unable to get the table name.
[Regular expression to extract SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672539/regular-expression-to-extract-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions are not full proof solution for extracting table names from SQL queries... As tons of things has to be considered, which would be trickier to express in RegX, and would break out in one or other cases....

You can use the following, ultra light, ultra fast library to do that in an elegant way

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.mnadeem</groupId>
  <artifactId>sql-table-name-parser</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
```

and Execute the following query

```
 new TableNameParser(sql).tables()
```

For more details refer the [project](https://github.com/mnadeem/sql-table-name-parser)

Disclaimer: I am the  owner of the library

Answer (score 0):

For that type of query

```
INSERT INTO 
    table_name 
  VALUES 
    (value1,'value which contains semicolon ;;;;',value3,...);

public static String regex = "(?i)insert into//s+(//S+)//s+"

    public static void printMatches(String text, String regex) {
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
      // Check all occurrences
      while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(" Found: " + matcher.group().replaceAll("(?i)insert into", "");
      }
    }
```