# Extracting sql queries from tomcat logs

Tags: java, sql, tomcat, logging, extract

I need to develop a JAVA application by following an object oriented design pattern for extracting sql queries from Tomcat logs. I have the log file. I need to extract sql queries from that file. 
I am new to this field. What are the basics i need to know to do this or give some good references.

As i cant share the whole log file , i am sharing some part of it:

(Dao.java:execute:73) SELECT ORDER_STATUS_TYPE_ID, NAME FROM ORD.ORDER_STATUS_TYPE
[DEBUG] [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1 05 Feb 2018 15:00:10] (TraceInterceptor.java:writeToLog:26) []Leaving TypeDaoImpl.getOrderStatusType(): 1062ms: [com.xyz.abc.api.is.model.type.OrderStatusType@2ac9ecc3, com.xyz.abc.api.is.model.type.OrderStatusType@76777395, com.xyz.abc.api.is.model.type.OrderStatusType@6ad8ddb7, com.xyz.abc.api.is.model.type.OrderStatusType@6738868f, com.xyz.abc.api.is.model.type.OrderStatusType@272c15f,

Comment: In your query run implementation method, if you print the query it will get logged in `catalina.log`. If you want to purely follow OO design, do check out ORM

Comment: I already have the log file. I need to extract sql queries from that log file. How do i do this

Comment: i shared some part of the log file. Once check it .

Comment: That's it `Dao.java:execute:73` can you edit this `DAO.java` ?

Comment: I only have the log file, I don't have access to dao file. Is it necessary to have dao file to do this?

Comment: That's alright check the answer, the list of sql commands is not exhaustive, I am leaving that for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting an answer assuming you cannot edit the `DAO.java`. If you can edit `DAO.java` introduce some characters like `||<<` to mark the starting and end of a printing query. That way you won't have make an exhaustive list of all the SQL commands.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\absin\\Desktop\\catalina.out");
            sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                if (line.toLowerCase().contains("select ") || line.toLowerCase().contains("insert ")
                        || line.toLowerCase().contains("update ")) {
                    // DO something with the found log entry
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
            // note that Scanner suppresses exceptions
            if (sc.ioException() != null) {
                throw sc.ioException();
            }
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if (sc != null) {
                sc.close();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Time taken : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " milliseconds");
    }
```

It prints a lot of log lines with query, and takes ~ 12 seconds on a 40 mb log file. You can also use regex, if you are familiar with them.

Comment: Will try to implement this and check if it's working

Comment: i tried using this code, the problem is that i have other debug statements in the log like  " selected id is 1111" .These statements are also getting displayed. Ther are many types of these debug statements starting with selected, updated . So how do i emit all of them . If only 4-5 types were ther i could omit them but its such a large file , so searching for each type and omitting is too tough.

Comment: `other debug statements in the log like " selected id is 1111" ` Note the code I have written above `if (line.toLowerCase().contains("select ")`, there is a space after the `"select ` and before ending `"`, you have missed adding that space. SQL queries will always be a space followed by select command

Answer (score -1):

Your question suggests that you already have a log file which contains the SQL. Although there are much better and faster ways to parse this file using different operating system tools but since you are constrained with using Java application, you can try using regular expression to parse the log files and get the queries. Some help with code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672539/regular-expression-to-extract-sql-query) .

Comment: @AbSin - I think the question clearly states that the intent is to develop the application in Java - " need to develop a JAVA application". He has not asked for opinion if is he wrong in using Java. And using a full text search engine like Lucene for just parsing - is'nt it a overkill ? You might have some compelling use case to use Lucene instead of just parsing.

Comment: i shared some part of the log file. Once check it .

Comment: I used solr and exposed a search for the log, which meant saving a couple of seconds it takes to just open the log file. Setting up solr was quite easy and the search was fast.

Comment: Definitely using solr will provide huge search features around the log entries. I must admit you had valid use case then :-)